# Retrieving name of object in firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list / an array of objects organized numerically which i consider the object name as an 'id'. I am using firebase and I can't figure out how to grab the id number itself. Any help would be great

```
//js
  myFirebaseRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
   var list = snapshot.val();
    $scope.items = list
     console.log($scope.items)
  })
//log $scope.items
[1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object //...
```

Answer (score 1):

with `angular.forEach` like that you can do something near :

```
angular.forEach($scope.items,function(key,value){
   //the key will contain your id
   console.log(key);
})
```

Comment: thanks but that logs the object and its items, not the id/name of object `Object {des: "Coffee Shop", name: "Joes Cafe", rate: "2"}`

Comment: I have to get that id in my template. what should it look like? {{key}} ? Not working

Comment: you mean that the object retreive have an attributes name ? If it's the case you can use value.name in the function

Comment: for display it in your template you can used ng-repeat. With something like <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in $cope.items"> {{key}}</div>

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
myFirebaseRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  //var list = snapshot.val();
  snapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot) {
    console.log(itemSnapshot.key); // if you're using 2.x that is key()
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this.  You use `obj[key] = value;` to set the id with a variable.

```
function update(node,key,value){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/');
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = value;
    ref.child(node).update(obj)
    .then(function() {
        console.log('Update Ran Successfully');
    });       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a real live example, using react and axios to retrieving the name of the object in firebase :

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/uri.json')
        .then(res => {
            let fetchedData = [];
            for (let key in res.data) {
                fetchedData.push({
                    ...res.data[key],
                    id: key //The key here holds the object's name !
                });
            }
        });
}
```